# How to deploy patched third party library with composer install

Tags: git, symfony, github, composer-php, git-submodules

First time asker - I've had trouble finding an answer to this one.

I've forked a GitHub repo of a vendor library I use in my application. This has allowed me to patch the third party vendor library. To introduce the forked repository into my application I've then used a git submodule - as per a standard "project-within-a-project". I've then removed the "require" line from composer.json that previously loaded the git repository.

However composer does not install the submodule / git repository in production when my production server runs "composer install".

My question: How can I deploy the patched GitHub submodule? Should I be using composer to download this on install?

Environment: PHP, Symfony, heroku

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

In your `composer.json`, add a [repositories key](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories) to the root:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "vcs": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/user/repo",
    }
]
```

and then reference the package name as usual in your `require` section. Composer searches for matches in each listed repository in order, falling back to Packagist if no match is found. The presence of a relevant repository entry will allow you to override the package in Packagist and get your custom version.

Comment: Thanks for this jbafford. I've used this line and it works. However from docs online, it's not entirely clear that the name of the bundle (used in super git repo's composer.json) should correspond to the name in the composer.json file (of the third party bundle / repository) and not the acctual repository name (although they are often very close). I hope that helps someone else out there that had the same problem I did.